# Errors after add Virtual Directory in IIS

Tags: asp.net, iis, iis-8.5

My web service on IIS can work well w/o a virtual directory (called by http://localhost). However, I want to call it like http://localhost/virtualpath.
So I added a virtual directory in IIS, but when I explorer website, it gives me the following error: 
[image]

What does this mean and how to solve it? (I'm using IIS 8.5)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It means exactly what the error says - you've tried to set a section in web config beyond application level. I'm assuming that you added the virtual directory under a pre existing website in IIS? What you want is to add a physical directory under the website with your app in and then simply right click and convert that folder to an application.

Comment: it works now. but when I add website and chose physical path to be my app folder, then I can only right click on and convert its sub folders. So in order to make it work, I'd have to add the parent path of my app folder and then convert the app folder.